# How to load jQuery with this webpack.config.js file?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, webpack

So I build the following webpack config file ([which I got from this repo)](https://github.com/pmachowski/production-angular-webpack-gulp/blob/master/webpack.config.js):

Now when I run *gulp serve* and *node index.js*, I get the following error:

*Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not definedtransition.js?9b13:59*

How do I modify webpack so that jQuery is configured properly to work with Angular and bootstrap?  Not even the bootstrap css is showing up which I'm puzzled about as well because that doesn't involve jQuery.

```
var path              = require('path');
var webpack           = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

var appRoot           = path.join(__dirname, '/src');
var bowerRoot         = path.join(__dirname, '/bower_components');
var bootstrapPath     = path.join(__dirname, '/bower_components/bootstrap/less/bootstrap');

module.exports = {
    cache: true,
    debug: true,
    singleRun: true,

    // The entry point
    entry: [
        path.join(appRoot, '/app/app.js')
    ],

    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, './static'),
        publicPath: './',
        filename: '[hash].bundle.js',
        chunkFilename: '[chunkhash].js'
    },


    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.less$/, loader: 'style!css!less'
            },
            {
                // require raw html for partials
                test: /\.html$/, loader: 'ng-cache'
            },
            {
                test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json'
            },
            {
              test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
            },
            {
              test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "file"
            },
            {
              test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/, loader:"url?prefix=font/&limit=5000"
            },
            {
              test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream"
            },
            {
              test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml"
            }
        ],

        // don't parse some dependencies to speed up build.
        noParse: [
            path.join(bowerRoot, '/angular-ui-router'),
            path.join(bowerRoot, '/angular-mocks'),
            path.join(bowerRoot, '/angular'),
            path.join(bowerRoot, '/less')
        ],
    },

    resolve: {
        alias: {
            bower: bowerRoot,
            'bootstrap.less': bootstrapPath 

        },

        extensions: [
            '',
            '.js',
            '.less',
            '.css'
        ],

        root: [appRoot],
        moduleDirectories: [bootstrapPath]
    },


    plugins: [
        // bower.json resolving
        new webpack.ResolverPlugin([
            new webpack.ResolverPlugin.DirectoryDescriptionFilePlugin('bower.json', ['main'])
        ], ['normal', 'loader']),

        // disable dynamic requires
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/.*$/, /a^/),

        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            'angular': 'exports?window.angular!bower/angular',
        }),

        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: __dirname + '/src/index.html'
        }),

    ],

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You already use [ProvidePlugin](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#provideplugin). So, you just need to add JQuery:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    'angular': 'exports?window.angular!bower/angular',
    '$': "jquery",
    'jQuery': "jquery"
})
```

Comment: Doing that I get `Error: Cannot resolve module 'jquery' in ....app/bower_components/bootstrap/js` when running `gulp build`

Comment: `bootstrap` dont have jquery in their package. You need to install `jquery`: `bower install jquery --save`